# How to fix a SIGSEGV in this simple doubly linked list implementation?

Tags: list, pointers, linked-list, rust, unsafe

I get a `SIGSEGV` error when running this code.

The code compiles, the debugger shows what looks like random addresses in pointers.

```
use std::ptr;

pub struct List<T> {
    head: *mut Node<T>,
    tail: *mut Node<T>,
}

struct Node<T> {
    data: Option<T>,
    next: *mut Node<T>,
    prev: *mut Node<T>,
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            head: ptr::null_mut(),
            tail: ptr::null_mut(),
        }
    }
    pub fn add_tail(&mut self, data: T) {
        let mut new_node = Box::new(Node {
            data: Some(data),
            next: ptr::null_mut(),
            prev: ptr::null_mut(),
        });
        let new_node_ptr: *mut Node<T> = &mut *new_node;
        if self.tail.is_null() {
            self.head = new_node_ptr;
        } else {
            new_node.next = self.tail;
            unsafe {
                (*self.tail).prev = new_node_ptr;
            }
        }
        self.tail = new_node_ptr;
    }
    pub fn remove_tail(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if self.tail.is_null() {
            None
        } else {
            let old_tail_ptr = self.tail;
            unsafe {
                if (*old_tail_ptr).next.is_null() {
                    self.tail = ptr::null_mut();
                    self.head = ptr::null_mut();
                } else {
                    let new_tail_ptr = (*old_tail_ptr).next;
                    (*old_tail_ptr).next = ptr::null_mut();
                    (*new_tail_ptr).prev = ptr::null_mut();
                    self.tail = new_tail_ptr;
                }
                (*old_tail_ptr).data.take()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My test adds ten integers `0..9` and them pops them. On second pop, I get

> signal: 11, SIGSEGV: invalid memory reference.

Comment: `let mut new_node = Box::new` will `drop` the allocated `Node` after it goes out of scope, leaving you with a dangling pointer in `let new_node_ptr: *mut Node<T> = &mut *new_node;`. And I'm not really sure why you are using unsafe code here

Comment: *simple* and *doubly linked list* — I see you haven't been properly introduced as to exactly how complicated such data types are if you care about memory safety... ([*Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/))

Comment: *"My test adds ten integers `0..9`"* That's only 9 integers.

Answer (score 1):

The following will fix the error. In `add_tail`:

- replace `let new_node_ptr: *mut Node<T> = &mut *new_node;` with `let new_node_ptr = Box::into_raw(new_node);`
- replace `new_node.next = self.tail` with `(*new_node_ptr).next = self.tail;`
- include `(*new_node_ptr).next = self.tail;` in the `unsafe` block

The error was due to obtaining the underlying pointer from the Box incorrectly.

After `let new_node_ptr: *mut Node<T> = &mut *new_node;` the Box continued to manage the memory pointed to by `new_node_ptr`. At the end of the block, the Box deallocated the memory automatically leaving `new_node_ptr` dangling.

To obtain a pointer with manual memory management and to release control of memory from the Box, use `Box::into_raw` instead of `&mut *`.

Comment: The "correct fix" would be to not go with pointers at all. Use a combination of `Option<Box<_>>` and you don't need any raw pointers. If you really want them, please use `Option<NonNull<_>>` to be certain, that you can't have null pointers.